# TypeError: createTestCafe is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am getting this error when I copied runner code from TestCafe site and try to run it. I have testcafe 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Below is my runner,

```
const createTestCafe = require('/usr/local/bin/testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
       testcafe     = tc;
       const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

       return runner
          //.src(['__test__/*.js', 'tests/func/fixture3.js'])
          //.browsers(['chrome:headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu', 'safari'])

          .src(['./__tests__/testcafe1.js'])
          .browsers(['chrome'])
          .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
       console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);

       testcafe.close();
    });
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe 'chrome:headless --no-sandbox' ./__tests__/*.js --hostname localhost"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "testcafe": "*",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3"
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.

TypeError: createTestCafe is not a function
    at Object.createTestCafe (/app/code/testcafe_runner.js:6:1)
    at Function._execAsModule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:50:13)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler._runCompiledCode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:150:42)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:174:21)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:180:21)
    at Compiler._getTests (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:86:31)
    at Compiler._compileTestFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:98:35)
    at Compiler.getTests (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:111:34)
    at Bootstrapper._getTests (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/bootstrapper.js:81:26)
    at Bootstrapper._bootstrapParallel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/bootstrapper.js:214:39)
```

I'm following the code from Testcafe https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to require TestCafe's executable file instead of the TestCafe's library. Likely it is located in `/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe` or in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe`. You can use the following command to find the path to your globally installed modules:

```
npm ls -g
```

However, it's really better to install TestCafe locally if you want to use it as a library. If you plan to run and distribute your test runner script as a standalone CLI tool, you can achieve it with creating a NPM package and adding your runner script to the `bin` section in `package.json`: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: I am getting the same error and I am requiring 'testcafe' only, I have it installed locally as a dependency but no luck. Seems like a Type error problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the keyword function

```
function createTestCafe(...)
```

Comment: If I were to add keyword "function", then I get following syntax error.SyntaxError: /app/code/testcafe_runner.js: Unexpected token (6:24)
  4 | let testcafe         = null;
  5 |
> 6 | function createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    |                         ^
  7 |     .then(tc => {
  8 |        testcafe     = tc;
  9 |        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler._compileCode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/es-next/compiler.js:57:32)

Comment: Oh my bad, i misread your question. It isn't the keyword function, as you are using the function there. Did you remember to export the function on the module? if you don't export, it won't manage to see how the which is the function address.