# How to do 'beforeEach' that changes the browser language in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am aware you can do it through CLI. But I already have a test that goes over every language by navigating to `/?lang=es` for example and validates a string for that Spanish.

There were changes made to the app and navigating to that query string doesn't work anymore, I would need to set the browser language for every test.

I could make a for loop over an array of langs (en-US for example) but im not sure how to set it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the runner](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402644/reference/testcafe-api/testcafe/createrunner). For example:

```js
//starts.js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

(async function () {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port1: 1337,
    port2: 1338,
  }

  const tc = await createTestCafe(options);

  const languages = ['en', 'gm', 'es'];

  await Promise.all(languages.map(async (lang) => {
    return tc
      .createRunner()
      .browsers(`chrome --lang=${lang}`)
      .src('./test.js')
      .run();
  }));

  await tc.close();
})()
```

```js
//test.js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture('Getting Started')
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button')
        .expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText).eql('Thank you, John Smith!');
});
```

Comment: I keep getting "TypeError: createTestCafe is not a function" Couldn't get rid of that error :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with my example. Do you use testcafe that is installed locally or globally? It is better to install testcafe locally. Look at [this question with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564472/typeerror-createtestcafe-is-not-a-function).

Comment: I have both, I yarn added it even. And I am not invoking testcafe as a file, Im just importing 'testcafe'

Comment: Please share a simple sample where this behavior is reproduced. Refer to this topic: [https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue). If you don't want to share it here, you can create it there: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml)

Comment: Ok, here's its the code: https://codeshare.io/AdlYQx

And here is the full error log: https://codeshare.io/gLRjOB

Comment: I see. The problem is that you `createTestCafe` inside `test`. However, the `createTestCafe` API is needed to run `test`s. It means that you should create a file, for example, `starts.js`. Put the code from my answer in this file, and it will run your tests from the `test.js` file. You can read more about it in the documentation: [https://testcafe.io/documentation/402662/reference/testcafe-api/global/createtestcafe](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402662/reference/testcafe-api/global/createtestcafe)

Comment: I am not using createTestCafe inside test. I've also tried to take that code to a different file and invoke it, it didn't work but im not totally sure how to link them up and use the runner in the test.

Comment: I updated the answer. Here are separate files for createTestcafe and tests.